# Not valid destination EPR - WSO2 Message Processor for Two Way Guaranteed Delivery

Tags: jms, wso2, throttling, two-way

I'm trying to implement WS load regulation (throttling) trough WSO2 Message Processor feature, the basic idea is that requests from client and reponses from backend are enqueued in two different message stores in WSO2. Two message processors take a message per second from the queue and send it to their respectives receivers. In the meanwhile the client waits blocked since is a two-way communication.

The schema for the mediation is this:

```
STEP 1: Client -> Proxy (Stores client request message in requests queue)
STEP 2: Message Processor "Requests" reads message from requests queue -> Sends to "echo" Enpoint -> Sends to "store" Sequence (stores echo response request message in responses queue)
STEP 3: Message Processor "Responses" reads message from response queue -> Sends to Reply sequence
STEP 4: Reply Sequence -> Client
```

My primary proxy is called Queue and I'm running a test with echo proxy as a backend endpoint.
This is the log output of the four steps of the flow

---

First receive request and store it in requests message store

```
2014-05-27 20:32:50,789]  INFO - LogMediator STEP = 1 Store Request
2014-05-27 20:32:50,793]  INFO - LogMediator To: 
/services/Queue.QueueHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:ff2f0caa-cab9-4ece-8bb1-223a7ba97bf2, Direction: request, Envelope: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><soap:Body>
  <echo:echoString>
  <in>test</in>
  </echo:echoString>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

---

After 1 second request message processor reads from requests message store and send it to echo endpoint

```
2014-05-27 20:32:50,813]  INFO - LogMediator WHEN = 2 Send Request to Backend
2014-05-27 20:32:50,814]  INFO - LogMediator To: 
/services/testt.testtHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, 
MessageID: urn:uuid:86b9f0d0-b970-4933-9be5-674799c9df4d, Direction: request, Envelope: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><soap:Body>
  <echo:echoString>
  <in>test</in>
  </echo:echoString>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

---

Response from echo is received and stored in responses message queue

```
2014-05-27 20:32:50,843]  INFO - LogMediator Step = 3 Receive Response from Backend and Store
2014-05-27 20:34:13,914]  INFO - LogMediator To: 
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: 
urn:uid:151B5E166555B48DAF818687464483291310017303, Direction: response, Envelope: <?
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns
soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:echoStringResponse 
xmlns:ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"
<return>test</return></ns:echoStringResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

So far so good, but at last step Message Processor reads the response queue and tries to send the message to client, but fails

```
2014-05-27 20:34:13,913]  INFO - LogMediator WHEN = 4 Send Response Message to client 
2014-05-27 20:34:13,914]  INFO - LogMediator To: 
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: 
urn:uuid:151B5E166555B48DAF818687464483291310017303, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml 
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns
soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:echoStringResponse 
xmlns:ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"
<return>test</return></ns:echoStringResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

2014-05-27 20:34:13,915] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender No valid destination EPR to send message
2014-05-27 20:34:13,915] ERROR - Axis2Sender Content-Type:application/soap+xml; 
charset=UTF-8; action="urn:echoStringResponse",<?xml versio
="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body>
<ns:echoStringResponse xmls:ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><return>test</return>
</ns:echoStringResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected
error sending message back org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No valid destination EPR to send message
```

---

It seems that "To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous" does not look as a valid EPR.

Question: Is it possible to achieve this kind of request buffering trough WSO2 with zero code?
If so, What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advcance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that It is an issue on correlation between your initial request with response in the client/proxy side.

You can correlate output message of out-queue with next action in a queue.
Check this article with similar scenario ["JMS Synchronous Invocations : Dual Channel HTTP-to-JMS"](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/JMS+Synchronous+Invocations+%3A+Dual+Channel+HTTP-to-JMS).

Regards.